# Failed attempt to expect and send

Tags: shell, ssh, git, expect, mingw

I'm trying to write a script which git clone.

my script:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git
expect "Enter passphrase for key..."
send "myPassword"
read -p "enter..."
```

and after run it I got:

```
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Enter passphrase for key...: |
```

and the program is waiting for password now, it seems like 'expect' and 'send' don't work properly.
What can be wrong in my script ?

Comment: Do you run this as a shell script or as a script passed to expect?

Comment: I open it by cmd.exe, I write 'myScript.sh' in cmd and it opened this script in git bash

Comment: expect and send are part of the [tag:expect] language, not shell. Do some searching in the [tag:expect] tag questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install an ssh agent in the client side , it will be more easy without the need to prompt for a password